# Debian: how to compare and compute fingerprint of an individual package?

Tags: debian

I wish to compare and compute the fingerprint of a package that I download from a Debian FTP mirror.

How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
md5sum <package>
```

Compare the result with the value listed at https://packages.debian.org

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there a more elegant way to compute and compare hashsums? There's a free, open-source utility for Microsoft Windows that allows you to copy and paste the hashsum provided by the uploader into a right-hand window. You press the `Calculate` button to compute the hashsum whose result will appear in the left-hand window. Finally you press `Compare` button to know the final result.

Comment: You can't get more elegant than the command line ;-) However, if you insist on a GUI, you could look at [Hash Checker](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=129309).